# Ajustar imagem dentro do canvas

Tags: javascript, html, front-end, canvas, fabric.js

Tenho uma página que permite inserir uma imagem dentro do elemento canvas e funciona perfeitamente.

Agora, o que eu preciso é uma forma de limitar o posicionamento da imagem dentro do canvas, não permitindo que fique sobrando espaços em branco, independente do posicionamento da imagem.

A opção de seleção da imagem está ativa. O reposicionamento é feito utilizando drag and drop.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso de algo igual este do [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjAWEqrdnL6skKQYsFM2?p=preview), mas sem precisar dar o zoom para movimentar a imagem.

**Canvas**

```
<canvas id="c" height="300" width="200"></canvas>
```

**Imagem**

```
<img id="imagem" src="images/teste.jpg">
```

**JS**

```
    var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        var imageSrc = "images/teste.jpg";

        fabric.Image.fromURL(imageSrc, function(img) {
            img.scaleToWidth(c.getWidth());
            img.scaleToHeight(c.getHeight());
            img.set('selectable', true);
            img.set('hasControls', false);
            c.add(img);
        });
```

Comment: Tentei rodar seu código aqui e não foi. Falta alguma coisa?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Fabric Js.

Comment: As imagens têm sempre a mesma proporção do canvas? Se não tiverem, como deseja fazer os cortes caso necessário?

Comment: Não, as imagens geralmente são maiores que o canvas. A ideia é permitir o enquadramento da imagem dentro do canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para prevenir que imagem fique dentro do canvas é necessário limitar o posicionamento do objeto **obj** que contem a imagem. A posição do topo e da esquerda não podem ser maior que 0.

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    preserveObjectStacking: true
});

var imageObj = new Image(), path = 'http://i.imgur.com/tEeSJcr.jpg';

imageObj.src = path;

imageObj.onload = function () {
    var image = new fabric.Image(imageObj);

    canvas.setHeight(250);
    canvas.setWidth(250);
    image.set({
        id: 'img',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        selectable: true,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        hasRotatingPoint: false
    });
    canvas.add(image);
};


canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj;
    obj = e.target;
    obj.setCoords();

    var boundingRect = obj.getBoundingRect();
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    var viewportMatrix = canvas.viewportTransform;

    //there is a bug in fabric that causes bounding rects to not be transformed by viewport matrix
    //this code should compensate for the bug for now
    boundingRect.top = (boundingRect.top - viewportMatrix[5]) / zoom;
    boundingRect.left = (boundingRect.left - viewportMatrix[4]) / zoom;
    boundingRect.width /= zoom;
    boundingRect.height /= zoom;

    var canvasHeight = obj.canvas.height / zoom,
        canvasWidth = obj.canvas.width / zoom;

    if(boundingRect.top > 0){
        obj.top = 0;
    }

    if(boundingRect.left > 0){
        obj.left = 0;
    }

    if (boundingRect.top < canvasHeight - boundingRect.height){
        obj.top = canvasHeight - boundingRect.height;
    }

    if (boundingRect.left < canvasWidth - boundingRect.width){
        obj.left = canvasWidth - boundingRect.width;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Deve-se evitar aumentar a resolução da imagem portanto a imagem tem de ser maior que o canvas. Depois é preciso verificar se a altura é maior que a largura para funcionar com vários tamanhos de imagem.

```
<canvas id="c" height="600" width="600" style="border:1px solid #000"></canvas>

var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var imageSrc = "http://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/formatos-de-imagem-2.jpg";

var w = 600;
var h = 600;


fabric.Image.fromURL(imageSrc, function(img) {
  if (img.width > img.height) {
    img.scaleToWidth(w);
  }
  else if (img.height > img.width) {
    img.scaleToWidth(h);
  }
  else {
    img.scaleToWidth(w);
  }

  img.set('selectable', true);
  img.set('hasControls', false);
  c.add(img);
});
```

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: podes ser mais específico?